# Why do we need to use FreeMarker in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp, jsp-tags

Why do we need to use FreeMarker to generate text output with .ftl file while we can use JSP file which includes html code?

Comment: JSP are "old-school", templating languages are "cool".

Comment: You don't **need** to do anything.